# Assigning variables to cells in a Pandas table (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I'm working on a script that takes test data from a website, assigns the data to a variable, then creates a pie chart of the responses for later analysis. I'm able to pull the data without a problem and format the information into a table, but I can't figure out how to assign a specific variable to a cell in the table.

For example, say question 1 had 20% of students answer A, 20% answer B, 30% answer C, and 30% answer D. I would like to take this information and assign it to the variables 1A for A, 1B, for B, etc.

I think the answer lies in this code. I've tried splitting columns and rows, but it looks like the column header doesn't correlate to the data below it. I'm also attaching the results of 'print(df)' below.

```
header = table.find_all('tr')[2]
cols = header.find_all('td')
cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
cols = cols[0:3] + cols[4:8] + cols[9:]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = cols)

print(df)

     A/1   B/2   C/3   D/4 CORRECT MC ANSWER  
0      6    84     1     9                 B  
1      6     1    91     2                 C  
2     12     1    14    72                 D  
3     77     3    11     9                 A  
4     82     7     8     2                 A
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want try something like this with 'autopct'?

```
df1 = df.T.set_axis(['Question '+str(i+1)  for i in df.T.columns.values], axis=1, inplace=False).iloc[:4]
ax = df1.plot.pie(subplots=True,autopct='%1.1f%%',layout=(5,1),figsize=(3,15),legend=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, something like this would be perfect, but (and I'm sure it's my own relative inexperience talking) when I tried inserting this into my script, I got a few codes thrown that said the chart used negative numbers, which I didn't see on either my data or the example code you showed me. How might I modify your example code to work? And I sincerely appreciate the response!

Comment: The negative number are because you are selecting more than just your counts.   If you limit your dataframe selection to just the counts of the answers, you will be okay.  Notice at the end of the first line of this code, I use .iloc[:4] just to get the counts only not the rest of the dataframe.

Comment: I guess I can't quite visualize how I would select only the counts due to my lack of experience with '.iloc[:4].' I've tried manipulating this number and appending it to the code that parses the data together, but I continue to get the "negative number" issue.

Comment: I am going to recommend you get @TedPetrou Pandas Cookbook plus the free 30 minutea of one on one tutorial.